# What is the rhythm of this rap?

Tags: rhythm

I figured out that it is 4/4, but I cannot for my life figure out what is the rhythm of the lyric "Row Row, Fight the Power". It is within 20 secs of start.

Can someone help me transcribe? Just that one measure.

This is the music:

Actually, is this correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will be closed but I think it can be useful to answer a question if an attempt has been made and some advice for future transcribing can be included so here goes:

You’re close but beats 2 and 4 are 16ths/dotted eighths, not straight eighth notes.

For rhythms like this you have to really feel the 16th note pulse and do your best to see on which 16th notes the notes fall on.

This is what you wrote. Consider a “t” to be a 16th note, either a rest or a note held over. I added spacers between the individual beats:

t t row t | t t row t | fight t the pow | t t er t

This is what it actually is:

t t row t | t row t t | fight t the pow | t er t t

Here your rhythmic notation which I edited:

[image]

As you can see, the second “row” and the “er” actually occur a 16th earlier.